# Converting a string to UInt8Array without charCodeAt

Tags: firefox-addon

I heard using charCodeAt was very slow to convert string to UInt8Array I was trying to figure out a way with `nsIStringInputStream` which I thought would be the fasest way?

So im trying to avoid this:

```
var str = atob('rawr');
var data = new Uint8Array(str.length);
for (var i = 0, e = str.length; i < e; ++i) {
  data[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

I'm not sure if I did it right, please advise:

```
var {Constructor: CC} = Components;
var BinaryInputStream = CC('@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1', 'nsIBinaryInputStream', 'setInputStream');
var StringInputStream = CC('@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1', 'nsIStringInputStream', 'setData');
var str = atob('rawr');
var _inputStreamScriptable = new StringInputStream(str, str.length);
var _inputStreamBinary = new BinaryInputStream(_inputStreamScriptable);
var data = new Uint8Array(str.length);
data.set(_inputStreamBinary.readByteArray(str.length));
```

thanks